# SessionStorage Slow Loading

Tags: javascript, vue.js, session-storage

I'm using SessionStorage data to display the username on the screen. The name should load after login, but the information is only loaded when I refresh the page (clicking on reload).
Does anyone know why?

```
    HTML
    <cv-header-name to="/"> Welcome {{ userName }}</cv-header-name>


    VUE
      data: function () {
       return {
       userName: [],
       };
      },
      mounted() {
        if(sessionStorage.getItem('name')) {
      try {
        this.userName = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('name'))
      }catch (error) {
        sessionStorage.removeItem('name')
      }
    }
    }
```

Before refresh
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tGzMV.png)

After refresh
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6yidS.png)

Comment: when are you setting the session storage?

Comment: do you do a full refresh of this component on login?

Comment: @DanielA.White On store. On the endpoint that has the user data
**sessionStorage.setItem("name", JSON.stringify(response.data.displayName))**

Comment: so you aren't causing this component to refresh. `userName` is only recalculated on mount

Comment: I think so. The login is configured in the backend.

Comment: @DanielA.White Do you know how I do this refresh? The information is in the browser's SessionStorage

Comment: yes - but you have the component to re-render.